mysqldump: Error 1412: Table definition has changed, please retry transaction when dumping table `chat` at row: 0
I have a cron job from an .sh file that is showing that error on title, content from the .sh file is this one:
#!/bin/sh
# THIS FILE IS MANAGED BY PUPPET
#
# mysqlbackup.sh - Backup script for MySQL databases
#         NOTE: This requires root to have a ~/.my.cnf file
#         containing root’s password to MySQL
# remove last backup
if [ -f /var/backups/mysql.sql.gz ]
then
    /bin/rm /var/backups/mysql.sql.gz
fi
# proactively set permissions
/usr/bin/touch /var/backups/mysql.sql.gz
/bin/chmod 600 /var/backups/mysql.sql.gz
# do backup
/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --all-databases --skip-extended-insert --events | /bin/gzip > /var/backups/mysql.sql.gz

Does anyone knows what can be happening?
Than
